# Install Qt5 on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu

During previous Ubuntu releases, one could easily install Qt 5 by using:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

`qt5-default` package is [no longer included](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=qt5-default) with Ubuntu 21.04.

How can I install the Qt 5 development package on Ubuntu 21.04?

Comment: They just renamed the packages I would guess: https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hirsute/qtbase-opensource-src

Comment: Why not use theirs online installer?

Answer (score 47):

**qt5-default** package is missed in ubuntu 21.04 repository, so you should just install all base packages by yourself by running command below

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
```

Comment: Also works for Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks!